# Brasero yields "SCSI error on write(1248864, 16)"

Tags: dvd, burning, brasero

I was using Brasero to burn a Win7 .iso for a friend (sorry, couldn't convince him to try Linux e.e) and when it was at 80% the process stopped with a "SCSI error on write(1248864, 16)".
I burnt some DVDs a day or two ago and it worked perfectly, and I know for sure the error isn't caused by the .iso file.
I'm using a DVD from a pack I bought today, they're Verbatim DVD+R, while the other day I was using DVD-R. My computer is pretty old but I changed the DVD burner a couple of years ago or so, and DVD+R are supposed to be compatible with more DVD players, so I can't guess where's the error.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Any idea will be welcome. Thank you.

PS: And please, ask me for information in case you needed it.

Comment: Are the disks dual-layer?

Comment: Did you try again?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ No, they're regular DVD+Rs (4.7GB, 16x)


@ psusi Yes, and it threw the same error D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SCSI error on write(1248864, 16)
```

The drive refused to write a chunk of 32 kB after many other
such operations have already succeeded. (Exactly 78054 write
operations did work. That's 2.5 GB.)

The error message is supposed to be accompanied by some SCSI
error code: 3 hex Numbers and their translation to human readable 
text.  E.g.:

```
[3 0C 00] Write error
```

Whatever, since the drive already worked on that burn job without
complaining, it is clearly a hardware problem. Drive and medium
did not like each other any more.
It is not a problem of burn software (in this case libburn, where
i am the developer) or of input data (the ISO image).

If this happens once in a large number of burns, then i would
count it as a particular bad medium.
If this happens often and with media from different manufacturers
then i would blame it on the drive. (Sometimes they go bad in
their youth, sometimes they die slowly after years of service.)

Comment: Thank you for your help and the info. I suppose the burner is guilty of this. Anyway, I tried to burn the .iso in another burner and it worked just fine, so the problem's kinda solved. Thank you again for your time :)

Comment: +1 Could you just clarify one thing, what did you mean by "If this happens once in a large number of burns, then i would count it as a particular bad medium."

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "write on disk" a window will pop up, then click on properties,
decrease the speed to its minimum and select burnProof (it will decrease the risk of failure).

It worked for me so good luck.